# Como creo un instalador que actualice la version previa instalada

Tags: vb.net

he creado una aplicacion cuyas actualizaciones las coloco en google drive, el programa descarga el instalador y lo ejecuta sin ningun problema, el problema esta en que no actualiza la version del programa, las modificaciones hechas en los formularios no se reflejan, queda la version anterior.

Comment: Imposible de responder sin saber qué está haciendo actualmente tu _instalador_ para _actualizar_ la aplicación....

Comment: es el mismo proyecto, solo que hago modificaciones a los formularios que la componen y vuelvo a hacer el instalador, se ejecuta, aparentemente instala todo pero al abrir la aplicacion de nuevo las modificaciones no estan, queda igual.

Comment: Esa parte la entiendo, lo que no me queda claro es ¿dónde "haces el instalador"? Es un programa que tu has hecho para instalar? ¿Utilizas alguna plataforma ya existente de instaladores?

Comment: el programa lo hago visual studio 2010, visual basic, el instalador lo hago con advanced installer ya que el visual studio no me da la opcion de crear el proyecto instalador, averiguando en la web encontre de modificar el instalador con orca y ponerle la opcion reinstallmode, pero tampoco me funciona. se instala pero no actualiza la version que se habia instalado antes.

Comment: Incluir esa información en tu pregunta ayudará a que encuentres la ayuda que buscas, editala y explica con mayor detalle tu situación. No olvides incluir las etiquetas relevantes... y creo que `vb.net` no es una de ellas, o al menos yo no le veo la relación. Creo que no está de más que, antes de editar tu pregunta, leas [ask]. Un saludo.